# Prolog - Need help finding a list within various options that satisfies my goal

Tags: prolog

Lets say I have a list of lists like this in prolog `[[1,2],[3,4,2],[5,6,1]]`.
I need to be able to get every lists of unitary lists that I can get out of that general list. That means that in the first list a 1 or a 2 can be there. On the second list a 3, 4, or 2 can be there, etc. But each number can only be repeated once in the final list of unitary lists.
What I mean is:

We find the first list with more than one element and choose one random

`[[1],[3,4,2],[5,6]]` we propagate the change and remove the 1 from the last list since we can't pick it there now. That I know how to do.

Now we go and choose the second list because it is not unitary and choose for example the first item `[[1], [3], [5,6]]`.

And we do that until we get a list of unitary lists `[[1], [3], [5]]`.

But there are other options like if we had chosen the 2 on the first list `[[2], [3,4], [5,6,1]]` -> `[[2], [3], [5]]`.

etc, etc. How can I in Prolog try every option until I find one that respects my goal?

What I have right now is this (the predicate is_solution checks if the input satisfies my goal):

```
solve(List, Solution) :-
    is_solution(List),
    Solution = List.
solve(List, Solution) :-
    does_something_here
```

Which I don't know what to do. I have the idea that I need to do some sort of DFS (I guess?) to transverse for every option of choices until I find one that fits but I've still not fully grasped the Prolog way of thinking. Can anyone help with this problem?

EDIT: To get a list of lists of unitary lists (triple nested like this [[[1,2], [3,4]], [[6,7], [3,4]]]) I built this which seems to work now since I fixed it

```
list_relation(List1, List2) :-
    maplist(sublist_relation, List1, List2).

sublist_relation(SubList1, SubList2) :-
    maplist(element_relation, SubList1, SubList2).

element_relation(Element1, Element2) :-
    member(X, Element1),
    length(Element2, 1),
    member(X, Element2).
```

Comment: The "triple nesting" is a new twist you added afterwards, which you didn't mention before. My solution shown is only for double nesting. But still, see my solution for a proper implementation of `element_relation/2`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much to go on, so I'll provide some hints.

First of all, this is a common pattern in Prolog where you want to describe a relation between two lists with a one-to-one relationship between the corresponding elements. Such a pattern might look something like this:

```
list_relation([], []).   % The empty list is related to the empty list
list_relation([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    % Code here that describes the relation between H1 and H2
    list_relation(T1, T2).   % Recursively check the relation on the tails
```

This is so common, in fact, there's a `maplist` predicate that can handle the mapping for you:

```
list_relation(List1, List2) :-
    maplist(element_relation, List1, List2).

element_relation(Element1, Element2) :-
    % Code here that describes the relation between Element1 and Element2
```

In your specific case, your elements are lists and you want to pick out elements. The "relation" between an element in the first list and a corresponding element of the second list can be described using the `member/2` predicate. `member(X, List)` succeeds with `X` being an element of list `List`.

I leave you with those clues.

---

As an addendum, your updated question overuses `maplist` and has an overly complicated way of expressing a list of one element. Your attempt does a sublist relation, which I did not say was necessary, nor is it.

So if you follow what I wrote above, your `element_relation` would be expressed as:

```
element_relation(List, [E]) :-
    member(E, List).
```

It's as simple as that. So the complete solution looks like:

```
list_relation(List1, List2) :-
    maplist(element_relation, List1, List2).

element_relation(List, [E]) :-
    member(E, List).
```

Note that `List` in the `element_list` corresponds to an element in your first list. That element is, itself, a list. The second  argument to  `element_list` gives the single-element list of the element chosen from `List`. This choice is made with  `member(E, List)`.

Finally, please use sensible names for your  predicates. I chose generic names to explain the principle. `list_relation` and `element_relation` are very general and do not describe your particular problem. You should name appropriately.

Comment: Well now my predicate list_relation(List1, List2) returns in List2 a list where it chooses one member which is good but it runs in an infinite loop when I check if solution(List2). Any thoughts?

Comment: @JVerdasca You'll need to show your code (you can edit your original  question) and explain what you tried to resolve the issue. Do a `trace` to see why it loops.